# Email address regular expression (RFC 5322) passed in to `match` does not work

Tags: javascript, regex, v8

In Google Chrome, this successfully matches the email address:

```
console.log('teddy@bear.com'.match(/^(([^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+(\.[^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+)*)|(".+"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/));
```

and this does not:

```
const regex = '^(([^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+(\.[^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+)*)|(".+"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$';
console.log('teddy@bear.com'.match(regex));
```

The only difference is that the latter has the regular expression passed in through a variable and not using the forward slashes.

I wonder how to get the latter work.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp  Pass it as a Regex Expression object?

Comment: You need to escape all the backslashes to keep them literal in the string. You got it right in a few places where you wrote `\\.`, but you missed it in most other places.

Comment: It's because a backslash in a string is interpreted first :
the value of your regexp string is:

    ^(([^<>()[]\.,;:s@"]+(.[^<>()[]\.,;:s@"]+)*)|(".+"))@(([[0-9]{1,3}.[0-9]{1,3}.[0-9]{1,3}.[0-9]{1,3}])|(([a-zA-Z-0-9]+.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use a string, the backslashes are interpreted as escape sequences when the string literal is being read, and they're not passed through to the `RegExp` constructor. You need to escape them to keep them in the string.

```
const regex = '^(([^<>()\\[\\]\\\\.,;:\\s@"]+(\\.[^<>()\[\]\\\\.,;:\\s@"]+)*)|(".+"))@((\\[[0-9]{1,3}\\.[0-9]{1,3}\\.[0-9]{1,3}\\.[0-9]{1,3}])|(([a-zA-Z\\-0-9]+\\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$';
```

I'm not sure why you want to do this using a string literal. If you want to put the regexp in a variable, you can still use a `RegExp` literal.

```
const regex = /^(([^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+(\.[^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+)*)|(".+"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/;
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, that works great! :) To answer your question regarding using a string literal, it's because the list of regular expressions come as strings from a config file. :)

Comment: If they come from a config file, then escaping isn't an issue. Escapes are only processed when the string is a literal in source code, not when it's read from a file.

Comment: Are you reading the file in a server-side language, and then using it to create the Javascript source code? In that case, you should probably use the language's JSON function to format the string properly.

Comment: If you want to know the proper way to do it, post the code that's actually having the problem.